# Org mode: How to restrain an inline image size in a table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, images, inline-image

I'm only interested in restraining the image size directly inside the org file and not for exportation. When the image is outside of a table it's easy to render it reduced with:

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 100
[[./path/to/file.jpg]]
```

But how can I do this if the image is inside a table? Is it even possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a solution that resizes _visually_ in the Org _buffer_ an image inside an Org table ? I'd say that it's possible by writing a hook function which resizes such images depending on the frame width.

Comment: @FirminMartin Yes absolutely.

Comment: Does the variable `org-image-actual-width` help? Set it to a number (of pixels) to restrict the width of *all* images to that width. Far from ideal, but it might help in your particular situation.

Comment: By looking at the source code where `org-image-actual-width` is involved, the key of my idea above is the variable `org-inline-image-overlays`. It provides an overlay list of all images visually displayed in the Org buffer. Then, using `org-at-table-p` and `overlay-start`, one can find out which images are in an Org table. The `'display` property of the overlays provides information of the image. So, one should be able to recreate the image with a different `:width` computed to fit the Org buffer and finally put the overlay. Will see if I can write an answer. No guarantee.

Comment: The tricky part arises when several images are present in different columns of the Org table.